# Drag and drop then move the object/image

Tags: javascript, jquery

When drag the object into the 'div1' , I couldn't move it. So need to get clone from the given image then drag it and drop into the frame and move that image anywhere inside the frame.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>      
<html>        
  <head>
    <style>
      #div1 { 
        width:700px;
        height:500px;
        padding:10px;
        border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
      }

      function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
      }

      function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
      }
    </script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" >
    </div>
    <br>
    <img id="drag1" src="img/gates/not_gate.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="10%" >

    <img id="drag2" src="img/gates/or_gate.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="10%" >

    <img id="drag3" src="img/gates/and_gate.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="10%" >

    <img id="drag4" src="img/gates/nor_gate.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="10%" >
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the js library you are using?

Comment: you can do it by using jquery, this is a [worked demo](http://plnkr.co/C204qZ) that can you inspire from it

Comment: `I couldn't move it` Why not? Just not clone it.

Comment: @Fawzan  I didn't use any js library here .I used to try d3.js .But I could not find the solution to get clone from the given image then move that clone.